# DeviceNotFoundException when executing XapDeploy

Tags: windows-phone-8, xap

I have just registered a developer account to deploy and execute apps on my Windows Phone device, and I have the following exception when I start the Xap Deploy Application :

*Exception of type
"Microsoft.SmartDevice.Connectivity.DeviceNotFoundException"* was thrown.

One button OK. Then i clicked on it and the XapDeploy Application close.

Do you have any suggestion, requirements or anything else ?

I precise : each time I run the XapDeploy Application, my WindowsPhone is connected to the computer and the screen is unlock.

Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: Did you developer unlock your device?

Comment: Yes, I started doing this before connecting and trying xap deploy